Angular material slider thumb indicator style issue
I am using Angular 17 (CLI Version: 17.1.0) with Angular Material version 17.3.10. I have standalone components setting disabled in my project. I am using mat slider in my component after importing MatSliderModule in the module and added this code as per the functionality.
<div *ngIf="item.question_type==1" class="que-opt-horizontal">
    <span>{{item.opt_hor_min_label_text}}</span>
    <mat-slider min="1" [max]="item.opt_hor_entry_count" thumbLabel tickInterval="1" step="1" showTickMarks discrete
        [disableRipple]="true">
        <input matSliderThumb [(ngModel)]="item.response_text" />
    </mat-slider>
    <span>{{item.opt_hor_max_label_text}}</span>
</div>

I am not getting the UI as expected in my app.
Expected slider UI

UI in my app

I am not sure why the indicator is not showing like a water droplet.
I have not added any styles externally related to the slider except this in the styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$assessment-ui-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$assessment-ui-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-green-palette, 700, 600, 800);
$assessment-ui-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$assessment-ui-theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (primary: $assessment-ui-primary,
                accent: $assessment-ui-accent,
                warn: $assessment-ui-warn,
            ),
        ));

@include mat.all-component-themes($assessment-ui-theme);

$primary: mat.get-color-from-palette($assessment-ui-primary);
$accent: mat.get-color-from-palette($assessment-ui-accent);

how can I change the indicator style as shown in the angular material documentation

show me your angular.json styles please

@AousMohammad https://nopaste.net/reeeNQr11y

actually, I was looking on the documentation for this slider I saw it's an empty div and have a background so it will look solid not dotted, so you need to apply custom ui component on it

@YashJain Please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back? feel free to update the versions to match your code and see if you are able to replicate the issue!

Working example, taken from the Material doc
For Angular version 18 + Material version 18 (might work for version 17 as well):
I deleted the thumbLabel attribute and added the discrete attribute as input as well:
 <mat-slider discrete
          class="example-margin thumb-on"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          [max]="max"
          [min]="min"
          [step]="step"
          [discrete]="kValue"
          [showTickMarks]="showTicks">
          <input matSliderThumb [(ngModel)]="kValue" #slider (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)">
        </mat-slider>

kValue is the updated value I get whenever the user changes the kValue in an input field (updates simultaneously the mat-slider and vice versa)
